# How to fix 'find' command in windows terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, filesystems

I wrote a Nodejs script which finds the last changed/modified file names.

For that reason, I am using `find` CLI command. I have one hidden file *.change* to compare other files to that one (modified times).

Here is a code below:

```
const es6dir = 'es6';
const path2dir = './htdocs/';

const exec = require("child_process").exec;

exec(`find ${path2dir + es6dir}/ -type f -newer .change`, (error, stdout) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`);

        return;
    }

    console.log(stdout);

    //update .change modified timestamp
    exec('touch -c .change');

}
```

Everything works fine if I run this command in *Git Bash* but if I use windows terminal it says an incorrect command.

Is there a simple way which will work for Linux and Windows terminal at the same time?

I would like to run this command in both platforms because some of the team members are working on Linux while others are using windows machines.

Comment: Touch in Windows is implemented by `Copy fname.txt+,,`.

Comment: Instead of using a command, create the file. `fs.writeFile` and use fs to compare changes, and stat a directory.

Comment: Rather than use the OS, why not use all the tools in nodes fs module?

Comment: Bash (Unix/Linux) [find](https://ss64.com/bash/find.html) and CMD (Windows) [find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)  are *very*  different.

Comment: @Keith Because this is just an example however the script is huge itself and it was written by the previous employee so I have to find out the way that works in both platform but as I understood I have to rewrite it and use Nodejs *fs* module.

Comment: You don't have to re-write it using `fs`, but in the long run it will pay dividends.  NodeJs is built on been cross-platform.   It might also make life easier if you do some NPM search's.  It's likely there is a module you could re-use to make life a lot easier.  I found this one that might make life easier -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-finder/v/1.2.0  Although the NPM doesn't say it, it's also `async` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross compatibility can be achieved through child processes or using `fs.stat` and `fs.writeFile`.

Stats returns an object like such:

```
Stats {
  dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 5077219,
  size: 11,
  blocks: 8,
  atimeMs: 1556271390822.264,
  mtimeMs: 1556271389892.5886,
  ctimeMs: 1556271389892.5886,
  birthtimeMs: 1556270439285.706,
  atime: 2019-04-26T09:36:30.822Z,
  mtime: 2019-04-26T09:36:29.893Z,
  ctime: 2019-04-26T09:36:29.893Z,
  birthtime: 2019-04-26T09:20:39.286Z }
```

As suggested in comments and an answer, I agree this would be a better approach. Here is how you can approach creating a new file, and checking creation date.

```
const fs = require('fs');
// Directory
const PATH = './';
// Get file's stats
fs.stat(`./.change`, function(error, stats) {
  if (error) { throw error; } // Throw if an error, file not found
  let time = Date.now(); // Current Time
  console.log(`Current .change: Created: `, stats['mtime']); // Created Time 
  // If current time > file creation time
  if (time > stats['mtime']) {
    // writeFile function with filename, content and callback function
    fs.writeFile(`${PATH}/.change`, 'Inside File', function (error) {
      if (error) { throw error; }
        console.log('File is updated successfully.');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful

Comment: @harry No problem, we all love to help.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Node's built-in [`fs.Stats`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) over platform specific commands or utilities. The `fs` module exposing [`fs.stat`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_options_callback) method returns the property [`mtime`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_stat_time_values) comprising last modified time in milliseconds.

Comment: Thank you. I will try *fs* module.